# Error con volley json

Tags: android, volley

Tengo el código siguiente:

```
   JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, URL_WEB_ECO, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    response.toString();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO: Handle error

                }
            });

    VolleySingleton.getInstance(applicationContext).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Pero no hay forma de recuperar el json que me ejecuta el php en mi servidor. Al hacer debugger la respuesta es [ ] https://miweb 0x93a63727 NORMAL 2. Tengo otras llamadas en la misma aplicacion que funcionan perfectamente y he comprovado que el archivo php responda correctamente con una salida json... Pero no hay forma... Alguna pista de donde me puedo equivocar?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Tienes que hacer un debug de `response`... dentro del método `onResponse` ... no veo que lo estés haciendo ahí, y tampoco se entiende qué significa esto: `response.toString();` ¿? Cambia eso por `Log.d("TESTVOLLEY",response.toString());` y revisa lo que te imprime el Logcat al lado de `TESTVOLLEY`

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano. Pero el problema és que al ejecutar debug no entra dentro de onResponse ni dentro de onErrorResponse... Solo me muestra la salida al marcar un breakpoint en la última llave de cierre.

Comment: No hace falta marcar breakpoints, con el `Log.d` verás los mensajes si entra en ese bloque y si no entra entonces tienes que revisar el flujo de tu código para determinar por qué no está entrando ahí.

Comment: Pues tenias razon, @A.Cedano, parece que el error esta en el json. Log.d me responde: TESTVOLLEY: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"quantity":"150.00","description":"Ingrés a cte. 2.12.2019","ts":"2019-12-04 12:52:11","balance":"147.26"},{"quantity":"-31.85","description":"cart #3886","ts":"2019-11-28 19:56:56","balance":"-2.74"},...] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObjec. Parece que si recibe la respuesta del servidor pero no lo puede convertir a Json, no?

Comment: Lo que estás recibiendo es un `JSONArray`, no un `JSONObject`. Saberlo es muy fácil: si empieza por `[` es `JSONArray`, si empieza por `{` es `JSONObject`. Por tanto, tienes que cambiar el tipo de tu petición a `JSONArrayRequest`  y a `JSONArray` en el `onResponse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás recibiendo es un `JSONArray`, no un `JSONObject`. Saberlo es muy fácil:

- si empieza por `[` es `JSONArray`,
- si empieza por `{` es `JSONObject`.

Por tanto, tienes que cambiar el tipo de tu petición a `JSONArrayRequest`  y el tipo de respuesta a `JSONArray`.

Los cambios que tienes que hacer son 4, te los he puesto en comentarios.

```
   /*1. Cambio aquí*/
   JsonArrayRequest mRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            /*2. Cambio aquí*/
            (Request.Method.GET, URL_WEB_ECO, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override 
                /*3. Cambio aquí*/
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d("TESTVOLLEY",response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO: Handle error

                }
            });
    /*4. Cambio aquí*/
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(applicationContext).addToRequestQueue(mRequest);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano! Estava un poco perdido... Es lo que tiene ser un novato! Un saludo!